# how to re-size image before saving to database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, resize, blob

I have a problem regarding on re-sizing the image before saving to blob data type using vb.net. I don't know how to resize the image.

here is my code in insert:

```
        Dim FileSize As UInt32

    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    pic_box_save.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
    FileSize = mstream.Length
    mstream.Close()
    MsgBox(FileSize)


    Try
        sql = "INSERT INTO clientreports(report_id, img) VALUES(@image_id, @image_data)"
        sql_command = New MySqlCommand(SQL, sql_connection)
        sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_id", Nothing)
        sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_data", arrImage)


        sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    MsgBox("Image has been saved.")
```

Please help me guys if anyone know how to solve this. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To create a thumbnail/resize image:

```
Friend Function GetImageThumb(ByVal orgBmp As BitMap, 
                    ByVal w as Int32, h as Int32) As Bitmap

    Dim thumb As New Bitmap(w, h)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumb)
        g.DrawImage(orgBmp , 0, 0, w + 1, h + 1)
    End Using
    Return thumb
End Function
```

For a data store, you'll probably need to convert the image to something else like a Base64 string or byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to resize image with specific requirements. Even you can maintain aspect ratio if necessary.

```
Public Shared Function ResizeImage(ByVal pImage As Drawing.Image, ByVal pWidth As Integer, ByVal pHeight As Integer, Optional ByVal pPreserveAspectRatio As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal pIsImageDisposeRequired As Boolean = True) As Drawing.Image
                Dim iNewWidth As Integer
                Dim iNewHeight As Integer
                Dim oNewImage As System.Drawing.Image
                Dim originalWidth As Integer
                Dim originalHeight As Integer
                Dim oPercentWidth As Single
                Dim oPercentHeight As Single
                Dim oPercent As Single

                Try
                    If pPreserveAspectRatio Then
                        originalWidth = pImage.Width
                        originalHeight = pImage.Height
                        oPercentWidth = CSng(pWidth) / CSng(originalWidth)
                        oPercentHeight = CSng(pHeight) / CSng(originalHeight)
                        oPercent = If(oPercentHeight < oPercentWidth, oPercentHeight, oPercentWidth)
                        iNewWidth = CInt(originalWidth * oPercent)
                        iNewHeight = CInt(originalHeight * oPercent)
                    Else
                        iNewWidth = pWidth
                        iNewHeight = pHeight
                    End If

                    oNewImage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(iNewWidth, iNewHeight)
                    Using oGraphicsHandle As System.Drawing.Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(oNewImage)
                        oGraphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                        oGraphicsHandle.DrawImage(pImage, 0, 0, iNewWidth, iNewHeight)
                    End Using

                    If pIsImageDisposeRequired Then
                        pImage.Dispose()
                    End If

                    Return oNewImage
                Catch ex As Exception
                    eCP.Excpetion.Untility.CommonUtils.WriteExceptionToFile(ex.Message, eCP.Excpetion.Untility.CommonUtils.LogFileTypes.Host)
                    Return pImage
                End Try
            End Function
```

Feel free to ask if any confusion.